# Adding latest record at the top of Azure Sql table

Tags: android, sql, azure

Iam following this tutorial :- http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/partner-xamarin-mobile-services-android-get-started/
to use mobile services with Azure.

Currently when I add items to the table, the data gets stored randomly. I want it to store the items in a such a manner that the latest record comes at the top of the list.

How can I do it?
Thanks

Comment: Generally in SQL, you'd use an `ORDER BY xxx DESCENDING` where `xxx` is a field, such as a timestamp.

Comment: Or if you have an identity column, order by descending on that. Make sure you create an index on the column you order on; as the data grows in that table, your sort order operation will slow down significantly without an index.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of that tutorial, the table in the database which has been created is using a `UniqueIdentifier` (equivalent to a `GUID` in code) as the Id. (presumably PK).

GUIDs are generated "randomly" and don't sort nicely in chronologically created order. It's not that the data is getting stored randomly. The Guid is randomly generated, and the table/index  stores it in exactly the correct place based on it's Id value.

At the end of the day, for such a small amount of information, the order it's stored in the table isn't really important so long as you can retrieve it in the order you want.

From the looks of the demo, the data table also has a `_createdAt` column on each data entity.  Have a look in the TodoItem & TodoAdapter code to find where it actually executes the query against the data store. It should be quite easy to add an `OrderBy` to that call to force the returned order to sort by `_createdAt`